# Echoing Standard input to Standard Output

Tags: c, echo, stdout, stdin

Write a program that will read standard input and echo each line to standard output with a line number and tab preceding it. When you run this program and enter lines from the terminal, lines of input will be interspersed with lines of output. If your system has output redirection and you redirect output to a file, the file will look like the input with the lines numbered.

Here is an example of how the script should work.

User input in **bold.**

Enter your text:

**This is line 1.**

1     This is line 1.

**This is line 2.**

2     This is line 2.

**This is the last line of input.**

3     This is the last line of input.

The last line will end the process.

Here is what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    printf("Enter your text: \n");
    while (1)
    {
        int ch = getc(stdin);
        fflush(stdout);
        if(ch == EOF) break;

        putc(ch, stdout);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I have been attempting at this for a few hours now to no luck, any help is appreciated. I basically cant get my script to display the example output. I can get my script to display the stdin as an stdout and thats all. This is a C assignment.

Comment: use gets & puts instead, then when gets gets a blank line, end the program.

Comment: Do _NOT_ use `gets` - it's probably the worlds most poorly designed function.

Comment: Do I get it right that the problem you have is to add the line-numbers to your input?

Comment: @Gread.And.Powerful.Oz write as answer, and really consider using `fgets`.

Comment: I'm sure this homework assignment is either for C *or* for C++...

Comment: @LapshinDmitry since it's a homework assignment, I want the OP to try to get it first and post his code if he doesn't get it working. It's a learning exercise.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your replies. I have already posted my attempt and would like to know how to navigate towards the solution.

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main(void){
    size_t no = 0;
    bool line_top = true;

    printf("Enter your text: \n");
    while (1) {
        int ch = fgetc(stdin);
        if(ch == EOF) break;

        if(line_top)
            printf("%zu ", ++no);

        line_top = (ch == '\n');

        fputc(ch, stdout);
    }
    fflush(stdout);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nice and sweet.  Minor point, why `size_t` which is the size for memory, not file lengths.  Maybe `unsigned long long`?

Comment: Well what about. In most compiler I think `unsigned long long` is used. But it can not expect to be by some compiler is necessarily so. So **It will must be examined whether having a size such as to expect.**

Answer (score 2):

To properly complete the assignment, you need to understand what is the line. The code you have in place reads and prints data symbol-by-symbol. This is not going to print the numbers requested!

There are two solutions here. First is to switch from reading symbol by symbol to line by line, and than print an ever incrementing counter every time you print a line. Second is leave reading symbol-by-symbol, but print an incremented number every time you've read a new line symbol from the input. A slight challenge here is that you would need a state - that is, once you've seen the new line character, you should remember that fact, but not print the number right away - this might be the last line in the input. Instead, print a number whenever your saved state tells you so, and reset the flag after this.

A separate question is what to do with the empty lines - do they participate in counter increment or not - but this is probably beyond the assignment.

Comment: Understood, however, I don't know how to do that. I know my script is far from what you have stated however is my basis workable? I don't understand why I'm having a tough time with the assignment.

Comment: I could solve your "problem" with about two-three lines added to your code [in my personal style it would perhaps be four-five, because I like to add extra braces for if-statements] - there are also lines that could be removed, if we wanted to shorten the code, but not much.

Comment: @AraMod, what exactly do you not understand here?

Comment: How to get my script to return the user input with a number and a tab. I don't know how to do it.

Comment: You need to recognise end-of-line, and after that, output the "line-number and tab".

Answer (score 1):

Ok you should *only* do what the assignment requires. Here's the most straight-forward solution I can think of:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char buf[1024];
    int num = 0;

    /* read a line as long as we can read (no error / EOF) */
    while (fgets(buf, 1024, stdin))
    {
        /* print line number */
        printf("%d\t", ++num);

        /* print what we actually read */
        fputs(buf, stdout);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Test run:

```
> ./numlines < numlines.c
1   #include <stdio.h>
2   
3   int main(void)
4   {
5       char buf[1024];
6       int num = 0;
7   
8       /* read a line as long as we can read (no error / EOF) */
9       while (fgets(buf, 1024, stdin))
10      {
11          /* print line number */
12          printf("%d\t", ++num);
13  
14          /* print what we actually read */
15          fputs(buf, stdout);
16      }
17  
18      return 0;
19  }
20
```

Comment: Other than using a narrow line count, nice and clear.

Comment: @chux thanks but what do you mean by "narrow line count"?

Comment: Narrow as in bit width: `int` is only guaranteed to range at least to 32767.  Using a less narrow integer like `unsigned long long` is less limiting given that files could have more than 4 G lines.  This is not a major issue.

Answer (score 1):

Code needs to keep track of the beginning of a line.  This can be done by reading a *line* using `fgets()` or by looking at individual `char`.

`fgets()` is likely faster, but it limits line length to some constant.

`fgetc()` gets 1 `unsigned char` at a time (or EOF).

The below follows OP's lead, yet adds the inner `while` loop.

Not much code needed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
  unsigned long long line_number = 0;
  int ch;
  while ((ch = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF) {
    printf("%llu\t", ++line_number);
    while (ch != EOF && fputc(ch, stdout) != '\n') {
      ch = fgetc(stdin);
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a c++ solution using `getline` and `cout`.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    unsigned int i=0;
    string s;
    cout<<"Enter your text: "<<endl;
    while (std::getline(cin,s))
    {
        cout<<++i<<'\t'<<s<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here a c solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int exit=0, i=0, newline=1;
    printf("Enter your text: \n");
    while (!exit)
    {
        int ch = getc(stdin);
        if(newline){
            printf("\n%d\t",++i);
            newline=0;
        }
        switch(ch){
        case '\n':
            newline=1;
            printf("\n");
            break;
        case EOF:
            printf("\n");
            exit=1;
            break;
        default:
            printf("%c",(char)ch);
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `Using namespace std` - I hope this will get as many downvotes as there are.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, however, my assignment is in C.

Comment: @SHR Fantastic however the solution seems to be in an inverse. The user input shout not have the number and tab. What the user inputs should be echoed into a line that contains the number and tab.

Comment: @SHR Is there a certain swap I can do to get the proper solution?

Comment: Code start by printing a `'\n'` before printing the first line #.  Hmmm?

Answer (score 0):

```
const int buflen = 1024;
char buffer[buflen];
int count = 0;
while (1)
{
    char* line = fgets(buffer, buflen, stdin);
    if (line == null)
        break;

    fprintf(stdout, "%d: %s\n", ++count, line);
}
```

Comment: Of course, this will give the wrong answer if a line is longer than 1024 characters - even if that is unlikely.

Comment: @MatsPetersson, of course, it's a limitation. I like the other posters solutions better than mine, too. Here's an upvote for you.

Comment: `fprintf(stdout, "%d: %s\n", ++count, line);`  will typically print 2 `'\n'`.  One  from `buffer` and a `'\n'` from the format `"%d: %s\n"`

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char line[1000];
    int lineno=0;
    while((fgets(line,1000, stdin)) != NULL)
    {
        lineno++;
        printf("%d  ",lineno);
        fputs(line, stdout);
    }
}
```

It will work as you are expected. It is a simple method to do this. You don't have to put the while(1) and if condition and break the loop.

Comment: Where's the line number? Nothing against late answers in general, but reading the other answers, you should have noticed you missed something. Also, `printf("%s", ...)` is using a swiss army knife to hammer a nail .. just use `fputs()`.

Comment: 1) `int fputs(const char * restrict s, FILE * restrict stream)` takes 2 parameters, not 3.  2) OP asked for "line number and tab"